# Java doesn't show menu text

Tags: arch-linux, x11, java, fonts, intellij

I startet netbeans/intelliJ/squirrelSQL after I didn't use it for a few days/weeks and now the menu doesn't show text. There are just the underlineds. My system:

- ArchLinux (everything up to date, everything installed via pacman)
- Gnome 3.12.2
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.0) (Arch Linux build 7.u60_2.5.0-2-x86_64)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
- Java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/bin/java

Any idea?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you do a reboot? I'd also try logging out and logging back in.

Comment: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the latest version of Java (7.u60_2.5.0-2).

If I rollback the versions of `jre7-openjdk` and `jre7-openjdk-headless` to 7.u55_2.4.7-1 using the pacman cache

```
# pacman -U '/var/cache/pacman/pkg/jre7-openjdk-7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz'
# pacman -U '/var/cache/pacman/pkg/jre7-openjdk-headless-7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz'
```

then Java programs seem to work correctly again. Hopefully, Java or Arch Linux will post an update to fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.

Using the system's anti-aliased fonts fixed the issue for me. You can find a description in the Arch Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/java#Tips_and_tricks

Short answer: put the following line into `/etc/profile.d/jre.sh`:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
```

You may have to log out and log back in for the new settings to take effect.

Comment: Note: if you don't want to modify global files (or if you can't, because of permissions), this answer can be adapted. I had the same problem with oXygen, and I fixed it by running it using `_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true' ./oxygen16.1` instead of simply `./oxygen16.1`.